# Strongly Typed IDs and JSON Schema generation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, jsonschema, strong-typing

I like the idea of Strongly Typed IDs and I am using it for some time. I use it also in DTOs without and major problems... till now. I have a use case where I need to generate JSON Schema from some classes which uses Strongly Type IDs like following:

```
[StronglyTypedId(StronglyTypedIdBackingType.Long)]
public partial struct TweetId
{
}

public class Tweet
{
  public TweetId Id {get; set;}
}
```

So, as described, `TweetID` is represented as `long` base type.

The problem arises when I want to generate JSON Schema from this type. I am currently using `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema` (I also tried some others) using this code:

```
JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
JSchema quotesSchema = generator.Generate(typeof(Tweet));
```

The result I get is:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "Tweet": {
      "type": [
        "object"
      ],
      "properties": {

        "Id": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/TweetId"
        }
      }
    },
    "TweetId": {},
  },
  "type": "object",
    "$ref": "#/definitions/Tweet"
}
```

But what I want is:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "Tweet": {
      "type": [
        "object"
      ],
      "properties": {

        "Id": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
    "$ref": "#/definitions/Tweet"
}
```

Do you have any idea how to achive this? `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema` is not mendatory.

Comment: Looking at the same issues myself @Rok. Am just wondering if you had any luck with answering this question yourself.

Comment: @Bigtoe, I gave up upon this idea because I also didn't find any solution. So now I am back on primitive types on DTO level, but I still use it in business objects.